How do you build a React component that can be dynamically resized via both the left and right side, with the other side staying in place?
I'm trying to build a resizable component that can be resized from either the left or right side. The user should be able to change the width of the component from either the left or right side. If the user resizes from the left side of the component, the right side of the component should stay in place. If the user resizes from the right side of the component, the left side of the component should stay in place. The user also needs to be able to see this resize happening in real-time as they drag the end of the component back and forth.
I've got this (mostly) working - resizing from the right side works fine, but when resizing from the left side, the right side wiggles back and forth slightly. I assume this is because lots of updates are happening very quickly to the same piece of state, but I'm not sure how to fix it. I tried using a ref to track the size values and just update the size state on resize stop, which worked, but then the component was only re-rendered after the resize was completed, meaning the user couldn't see the resize happening in real-time, which is a requirement here.
I've tried two different libraries for resizing components, react-resizable and re-resizable, and both produce the same issue.
Here's a gif of what's happening:

And here's a CodeSandbox with the minimum code I could put to reproduce the issue. Here's the code if you don't want to hop:
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Resizable } from "re-resizable";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [size, setSize] = useState({ left: 100, width: 400 });

  const [dragStartSize, setDragStartSize] = useState(null);

  const onResize = function ({ delta, direction, size }) {
    setSize((prevSize) => {
      if (!dragStartSize) {
        return;
      }

      let newLeft = size.left;

      if (direction === "left") {
        newLeft = dragStartSize.left - delta.width;
      }

      let newWidth = dragStartSize.width + delta.width;

      return { ...prevSize, left: newLeft, width: newWidth };
    });
  };

  return (
    <div style={{ backgroundColor: "green" }}>
      <Resizable
        style={{
          position: "relative",
          left: `${size.left}px`,
        }}
        enable={{
          top: false,
          right: true,
          bottom: false,
          left: true,
        }}
        size={size}
        onResizeStart={() => {
          setDragStartSize(size);
        }}
        onResize={(event, direction, elementRef, delta) =>
          onResize({ delta, direction, size })
        }
        onResizeStop={(e, direction, ref, d) => {
          setDragStartSize(null);
        }}
      >
        <div
          style={{
            backgroundColor: "orange",
            padding: "5px",
            border: "2px solid black",
          }}
        >
          Resizable box
        </div>
      </Resizable>
    </div>
  );
}


Notice that when you quickly resize the resizable box from the right side, the left side stays nicely in place. But when you quickly resize it from the left side, the right side wiggles back and forth.
How can I make this work such that the right side doesn't wiggle back and forth? Or is there maybe a library that does this for you already? I just can't figure it out.

What happens if you change  useState({ left: 100, width: 400 }) to  useState({ right: 100, width: 400 })? Also, please make a runnable snippet in your question to make it easier for us to debug.

@AHaworth if I change it to "right: 100" then moving the left side causes the right side to shrink/grow instead. Basically then the left side doesn't move at, and resizing on both ends causes the right side to grow/shrink. I couldn't figure out a way to include the re-resizable library in Stack Overflow's code snippets tool but I'm happy to try to post the code to another alternative than CodeSandbox if that would help.

The snippet editor lets you include libraries.
